# Print's differently on my machine v/s client's

Tags: html, css, printing

I have written print.css for a page to make it printer friendly. Now when i take the printout of this page at my end in ie7 its clean and in accordance with screen. But on the client side its showing background images some lines etc. I am not sure whats different between the two can somebody help me with that.

Comment: What's wrong with the question atleast write something!! i can correct myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt get any help on SO. So i googled it more and found a guy having same problem. Then found that its a IE 7 Setting.

Go to tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Printing > and there is a option that you want to see background images or not.

So know after seeing ur print preview in both the setting you can decide what all modifications you need to make to get the printed page look good in both the cases. Like i did background:none; for body. And kept rest of the things same.